# Replace with 0 when retrieving data from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am filling in the values ​​of a column in a data frame from the values ​​present in a matrix. The search for the value is performed from two columns called `e1` and `e2`. But it is possible that in any of these columns contain strings that are not present in the matrix. This of course gives error, but I would like to know if it is possible to continue filling with a 0 that non-existent value.

```
x<-cbind(c(0.3,0.35,0.35,0),c(0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2)
,c(0,0.6,0.1,0.3),c(0.5,0.25,0.25,0))
colnames(x) <- c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(x) <- c("A","B","C","D")

y<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
,c("A","A","B","A","B","A"),c("D","C","C","D","D","J")))
colnames(y) <- c("id","e1","e2")

index_df = y%>% select(e1,e2)
colnames(index_df)<-c('rows','cols')

y$l<-x[as.matrix(index_df)]
```

> Error in x[as.matrix(index_df)] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `match` row and column names of `x` with `e1` and `e2` columns of `y` and then use it to subset the values from `x`.

```
y$l <- x[cbind(match(y$e1, rownames(x)), match(y$e2, colnames(x)))]

y
#  id e1 e2    l
#1  1  A  D 0.50
#2  2  A  C 0.00
#3  3  B  C 0.60
#4  4  A  D 0.50
#5  5  B  D 0.25
#6  6  A  J   NA
```

This will return `NA` for non-matching values which if needed can be changed to 0 by doing

```
y$l[is.na(y$l)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to create an index based on the occurrence of values with `%in%`.  Here, 'J' is not a columnname for 'x'.  So using 'i1', we create a logical index and update only those rows that have column names matching with the 'e2'. Now, we can directly use the OP's syntax

```
i1 <- index_df$cols %in% colnames(x)
y$l[i1] <- x[as.matrix(index_df[i1,])]
y
#  id e1 e2    l
#1  1  A  D 0.50
#2  2  A  C 0.00
#3  3  B  C 0.60
#4  4  A  D 0.50
#5  5  B  D 0.25
#6  6  A  J   NA
```